# How to make a min date come over into my MVC action correctly

Tags: javascript, .net, datetime

I want to represent a .NET min date (1-1-1) in javascript and have it parsed by .NET correctly when I call my action. In javascript, if I create a date object equal to 1-1-1, .NET parses it as 1-1-2001, rather than the year 1 (i.e., 0001). How do I get .NET to parse it as the actual DateTime.MinDate value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
"1-1-0001"


DateTime.Parse("1-1-0001") will result in DateTime.MinValue
```

Comment: You're right. The problem was that I was using javascript Date functions to create the min date value on the web page. THAT was reducing the year to one digit. When I saw your code, it occurred to me to just create a string value (like you're using) rather than an actual date type. That works.